# override to_xml to limit fields returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-to, respond-with

using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3, i would like to limit the fields returned when a record is accessed as json or xml (the only two formats allowed).

[this](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with) very useful post introduced me to respond_with and i found somewhere online that a nice way to blanket allow/deny some fields is to override as_json or to_xml for the class and set :only or :except to limit fields.

example:

```
class Widget <  ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
  end

  def to_xml(options={})
    super(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
  end
end

class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def index
    respond_with(@widgets = Widgets.all)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@widget = Widget.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

this is exactly what i am looking for and works for json, but for xml "index" (GET /widgets.xml) it responds with an empty Widget array.  if i remove the to_xml override i get the expected results.  am i doing something wrong, and/or why does the Widgets.to_xml override affect the Array.to_xml result?

i can work around this by using

```
respond_with(@widgets = Widgets.all, :except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
```

but do not feel that is a very DRY method.

Comment: maybe using something like acts_as_api would be a better approach in general though.

Comment: think you have to call the method you override `as_xml`, similar to `as_json`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your to_xml method, do the following:

```
def to_xml(options={})
  options.merge!(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at])
  super(options)
end
```

That should fix you up.

Comment: This works! Helped me with a bug in CarrierWave when returning XML.

Comment: This was also the proper way to go in Rails 4 with Active Admin 1.0.0-pre2 in order to exclude columns from XML output (since I wasn't able to find a hook within ActiveAdmin in order to change XML output the same way you can with CSV output).