# Restrict specific fields in the response of rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a controller action like

```
def index
  @videos =  Video.all.to_a

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @videos }
    format.json { render :json => @videos }
  end
end
```

Video has attributes `name` and `title`.

I want the return xml to contain only `title`.

How do I restrict it from the response.

Answer (score 41):

Doing it like this:

```
def index
  @videos =  Video.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @videos.to_xml( :only => [:title] ) }
    format.json { render :json => @videos.to_json( :only => [:title] ) }
  end
end
```

You can find more info about this at [the serialization documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html).

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `select` clause on your `Video.all` query, specifying the fields you want to include.

```
@videos = Video.select("id, name, title").all
```

Also, you shouldn't need to call `to_a` on your query.

Comment: As well, I dont believe you need the :all on this query

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `.to_xml` method inside `video.rb`,

e.g:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_xml(opts={})
    opts.merge!(:only => [:id, :title])
    super(opts)
  end

end
```

And then call `respond_with(@videos)` in you controller.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685662/override-to-xml-to-limit-fields-returned).

Answer (score -6):

a fast way would be to use **:pluck**, if you are just returning an array of titles (I am guessing no :id) , then this would be very fast

```
def index
  @titles = Video.pluck(:title)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @titles }
    format.json { render :json => @titles }
  end
end
```

**:pluck** will be way faster than any of the other options because it returns an array with just the data requested.  It doesn't instantiate an entire ActiveRecord Object for each database row.  Because its ruby, those instantiations are what take most of the time. You can also do :

```
@videos_ary = Video.pluck(:id, :title)
response = @videos_ary.map {|va| { id: va[0], title: va[1] }}
```

if you dont want to get your SQL pencil out, this is pretty good