# How can I make an ActiveModel::Serializer attribute optional at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I am trying to allow an API request to specify what fields to return on an object.  I can retrieve the object with only the fields specified, but when it is serialized, it throws an error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: x)
```

How can I achieve this functionality with `ActiveModel::Serializer` and is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

I've found this question while searching for a good alternative to remove optional fields from the json response.

The gem `active_model_serializers` does have a solution for this. You just need to pass a conditional to the `attribute` method in the serializer declaration.

```
class MySelectiveSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :anything
  attribute :something, if: -> { object.something.present? }
end
```

Perhaps 3 years ago a solution like this didn't exist, but it is available now. :)

Cheers.

Comment: In what version was this introduced? Can you link to a reference?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `Serializer.attributes` method call each field using the `ActiveModel.read_attribute` method. This method will apply some validations, like `validates_presence_of` at the model's definition, that will raise the exception. To avoid it I give *three bad solutions* and **after** a better and simple one:

- Change the model definition, but you will miss your validation.
- Overwrite the method `ActiveModel.read_attribute` to handle this behavior, you will get new challenges.
- Overwrite the `Serializer.attributes` and instead of call **super**, call `object.attributes`.

But the best option will be create a new serialize class, to avoid besides effects, with the only fields that you want. Then specify this at the controller class:

```
render json: People.all.reduced, each_serializer: SimplePersonSerializer
```

---

**Edit 1**

The right answer should be the one from [Maurício Linhares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919220/2985644).

```
render json: result.to_json( only: array_of_fields )
```

Comment: The final suggestions doesn't meet the challenge. OP wants the API consumer to be able to specify any combination of fields rather than a specific, predefined subset.

Comment: @Adamantish thanks for this, I didn't realize that it should be flexible, my bad =(

Answer (score 2):

You can remove attributes from serializer, but they should exist.

```
class SomeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :something

  def attributes
     super.except(:something) if something
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize attributes by implementing [`filter`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#attributes) method in your serializer. Note, that I describe latest stable (for the time of the writing this post) `0.9.x` branch.

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :author

  def filter(keys)
    if scope.admin?
      keys
    else
      keys - [:author]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem filter is called after the looking for all the attributes so error is still thrown.