# Get specific json data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this json data (actual data is a lot longer, that's why I need only 2)

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "event_id": 1,
    "creator_id": 1,
    "event_name": "Poker",
    "cruise_ship_name": "Royal Cruise",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "event_id": 2,
    "creator_id": 1,
    "event_name": "Ballroom",
    "cruise_ship_name": "Celebrity Infinity",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "event_id": 3,
    "creator_id": 1,
    "event_name": "Tennis",
    "cruise_ship_name": "Mediterranean",
  }
]
```

I want to combine all data and get only specific fields (event_name and cruise_ship_name)

So in my final json format

it will be:

```
[
  {
   "event_name": "Mexican Fiesta",
   "cruise_ship_name": "Celebrity Infinity",
  }
]
```

I have been looking at this example:

```
@object.to_json {:include => [ :assocation_a, :assocation_b ]}
```

but not sure what :association_a and :association_b are.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919147/restrict-specific-fields-in-the-response-of-rails-controller

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array of hashes:

```
events = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "event_id": 1,
    "creator_id": 1,
    "event_name": "Poker",
    "cruise_ship_name": "Royal Cruise",
  },
  ...
]
```

You can iterate through each value in your hash, only keeping values of interest:

```
events.each do |event_hash| 
   event_hash.keep_if { |key, _| [:event_name, :cruise_ship_name].include?(key) }
end

puts events
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json) method accept parameters which allow you include specific attributes:

```
@object.to_json(only: [:event_name, :cruise_ship_name])
```

The `include: :assocation_a` option to  object, allowing the object association in the `assocation_a` model to be converted to JSON as well.